# Drupal website with 20 languages, Should I go with Multisites OR one Multilingual site?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, translation, multilingual, multisite

So, I have to build a website with 20 different languages, each language will have custom domain name. The Website will display products with details, some of the products will be available in two under tow different domains(language/ region), the others will be only for one. Accounts on the website will be available for people from the company to put translation and manage their own content based on their own language, BUT we need some users can have ability to access all of the translation with one login.

Now, by default I was thinking about One website with multi language, then I thought about having multisites installation since that make it easy for the people who have to translate their own content without dealing with seeing the other content or hit 'Translation button'.

**Pros and Cons I came up with:**

- it would be easier to have for the people from different countries to
  deal with their own content and have full customization to their own
  instance, While for one instance site it will be complicated since I
  have over 50,000 products.
- it would be hard in the future to add new functionality for the
  Multisites since we have to add it for the 20 instance. (not sure if
  thats correct), while if we use One website it will be one change for
  all.
- What about one login?? not sure if there is a module support that.

But yeah this is my situation, Please help me from your experience to decide which one would be the best choice and why. Take in mind all of the will share same look and feel. But they will be 20 languages with 20 custom domains and 10s of thousands products and nodes. Should I go with D7 or D8?

**Thank you, I appreciated.**

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for [Programmers StackExchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Multi language is your solution here because you are sharing product and administrators/webmasters.
The module domain access (https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) will give you what you need in term of domain name management.

Multisite does not share configuration so if you want to add something to all domain you will have to configure it 20 times.
And if you need to add some modules for only 1 domain you can use Context (https://www.drupal.org/project/context) to specify your rules of display.

If I were you I will go with D7 because there is lot more stuff available right now, but the migration will be hard if you think about migrate to D8. And many modules are not develop for D8 right now so it s more secure to use Drupa7.